# How to use IN operator with RANGE in mongo

Tags: mongodb

Why I am getting an error while running this?

```
db.collection.find({"class": "ALL", "YEAR": {"$in": {"$range": [2017, 2020]}}})
```

Here is the error:

```
{
    "code" : NumberInt(2),
    "codeName" : "BadValue",
    "message" : "$in needs an array",
    "name" : "MongoError",
    "ok" : 0
}
```

Suggest, what's wrong in my code line.

Comment: $range is used in an aggregate pipeline but you can use it in a find() query with $expr.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you dont need `$in`.

`$in` is used if you have an array of values and want to check if your searching field match any of those values in the array, witch isnt the case at this problem.

Why you dont use greater-then-equal `$gte` and lower-then-equal `lte` ?

```
db.collection.find({"class": "ALL", "YEAR": { $gte: 2017, $lte: 2020 } })
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because `$in` needs an array and it's getting an object now

```
db.collection.find({"class": "ALL", "YEAR": {"$in": [{"$range": [2017, 2020]}]}})
```

Can you try this out?